# How to copy code for trello rule from command builder

Tags: rules, trello

there are several examples for trello rules as plain code available or the code can be created with the trello [command builder](https://butlerfortrello.com/builder.html). But I can not find any way how or where to paste the code in my trello board.

thanks for hints!

kind regard, P